# How to insure rsync gets complete file if remote cron deletes it during transfer

Tags: linux, rsync

Alternate title: How can I prevent the deletion of a file if rsync (or any other app) currently has the file open for reading?

I have a cron on my live system that dumps a database to a backup file every 30 min.

On my backup system I have a cron that runs rsync to fetch that backup file, also every 30 min.

I thought about creating lock files and using them to tell the remote if it's safe to fetch the file or visa versa. I also thought about having the dump script create file names in a rotation and create a "name" file that the remote fetches to know what file is "safe" to retrieve. I know I can synchronize the cron jobs but I'm wondering if there is a better, safer way.

Is there some OS feature I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: Create a dump with a temporary name then rename when it's done. Presumably, you need to have both a temporary and a destination files placed on the same filesystem.

Comment: I assume that once rsync opens the file to read, it has a link to it even if the name changes and can continue reading from it?